# Can someone help me start off my project in c++?

Tags: c++, random

Children often play a memory game in which a deck of cards containing
matching pairs is used.
The cards are shuffled and then placed face down on a table. The players then take turns and select
two cards at a time. If both cards match, they are
left face up; otherwise, the cards are placed face
down at the same positions. Once the players see the
selected pair of cards and if the cards do not
match, then they can memorize the cards and use their memory to select the next pair of cards.
The game continues until all the
cards are face up. Write a program
to play the memory game.
Use a two-dimensional array of 4 rows and 4 columns for a deck of 16 cards with 8 matching
pairs. You can use numbers 1 to 8 to mark the
cards. Use random number generators to randomly
store the pairs in the array. Use appropriate functions in your program, and the main program
should be merely a call to functions.

This is the project that I got for my c++ class. The issue I was having was using the random number function and putting it in the 4x4 array. Can someone guide me in the right direction? This is what I got so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int board[4][4];
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    int row = rand(), column = rand();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)

        board[row];

        for (int c = 0; c <= 4; c++)



            board[row][column];
            cout << board[row][column] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Besides fixing the rand(). Change `<=` to `<` in your for loops. You do not have 5 rows of 5.

Comment: Your code has a lot of horrible errors. First put some effort in it before asking here. I am sure you will be able to reduce the errors a bit by yourself so people here can help you hunting down the more difficult issues. Afterwards update your question and describe what output you exepect and what you get.

Comment: And learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`rand` gives a number between **0** and **RAND_MAX** (guaranteed to be at least **32767** by the C standard, actual value depends on the standard library implementation). Write this:

```
row = rand() % 4;
col = rand() % 4;
```

Comment: I did that and got 4 rows of the same number. I'm not really understanding whats going on.